# BoolToVisibility not working on IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` for display or hide a `TimePicker` based on a radio button checked:

```
 <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />

<RadioButton Content="Enable" IsChecked="True" Name="ExportByHour"/>
<RadioButton Content="Hide" />
<materialDesign:TimePicker
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ExportByHour, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"
            IsInvalidTextAllowed="False"
            Is24Hours="True"/>
```

unfortunately I got this working only on `Visibility` property, why?

Comment: At first glance, a visibility converter would return either `Visible`, `Collapsed`, or `Hidden`, not return an actual `True` or `False` which the `IsEnabled` property would require.

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the purpose of the BoolToVisibility convertor. It can only be used with a Visibility property.

The Visibility property has three states, Visible, Collapsed and Hidden.

A common use-case is to bind the Visibility property of a control to a boolean property in the view model, so that true and false are translated to visible and collapsed. This is where you would use the BoolToVisibility convertor.

It makes no sense to use this convertor on other properties. IsEnabled is a boolean property, which can be bound directly to a boolean property in the view model without using a converter.